# Problems with PIG_HOME path ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig

I have RoR project and after build and run him I catch in log next problems:

```
PIG_HOME not set: requires Pig >= 0.7.0
2016-01-22 14:31:56 +0200 Fail to run pig. exit
```

After it I download and set PIG_HOME path and JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.15.0
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_71
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then restart PC and try again build and run project, but problem not fixed. I don't know why it happens, and how to fix it. Help me please, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add in /etc/profile

```
PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.15.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_HOME
export PATH
```